# firewall-cmd configure destination NAT

Tags: nat, redhat-enterprise-linux, firewalld

I am trying to configure destiation NAT on a RHEL 7.4 server. I want any traffic generated for 10.10.10.10:443 to go to 10.20.20.20:443.

After some Googling I used following direct rule:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -d 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.20.20:443
```

I could see it in the PREROUTING_direct chain.

```
# iptables -t nat -vxnL PREROUTING_direct
Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.10.10.10          tcp dpt:443 to:10.20.20.20:443
```

But when I telnet to 10.10.10.10:443 it doesn't redirect to 10.20.20.20:443

I do not see the rule is hit (pkts = 0, bytes = 0). Event tcpdump doesn's how any traffic going to 10.20.20.20.

Cheers,

J

Comment: Just realised that as the traffic was generated on the machine, I should have used OUTPUT chain instead of PREROUTING. Following worked for me: `firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -d 10.30.200.8 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.70.7.8:443`

Answer (score 2):

The following command works 100%

All TCP/443 sourced from 10.10.10.10 will be forwarded to destination 10.20.20.20 on TCP 443

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address="10.10.10.10" forward-port to-addr="10.20.20.20" to-port="443" protocol="tcp" port="443"'
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It also works with nftables backend.